# REGEX Google Analytics Goals

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I am setting up a RegEx goal in Google Analytics and my RegEx is not working.

I try to track all DOMAIN/de/spiel-gestalten?...

I use this RegEx:

```
    \/de\/spiel-gestalten(\?)(.*)
```

Does somebody see in this RegEx what I am writing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have to escape the forward slashes:

```
/de/spiel-gestalten/\?(.*)
```

This would capture:

```
/de/spiel-gestalten/?a;slkdjf;lkajsd;flkj
/de/spiel-gestalten/?id=blah
etc.....
```

Comment: I really appreciate your Answer! Thank you. I am sure its right, but sadly there must be a other reason why its not working.